# Create a SSH session connect to device through a terminal server

Tags: python, ssh, telnet

I want to connect to a network device. But in out policy, I have to ssh successfully to a terminal server first, then from this one, ssh to network device. In Python, I use Paramiko :

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
print("OTP : ")
otp = raw_input()
ssh.port=9922
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect('10.0.0.1',9922,username='khangtt',password=str('12345')+str(otp))

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('whoami')
stdin.close()
for line in stdout.read().splitlines():
    print(line)
```

Connect to server sucessfully, I can see my username in the output. But I don't know how to SSH to device. I used this but nothing happen to set input user/pass :

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('telnet 10.80.1.120')
stdin.close()
for line in stdout.read().splitlines():
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using paramiko, use the documentation here: https://pynet.twb-tech.com/blog/python/paramiko-ssh-part1.html. Its very explicit.

Or you can also try the codes here to connect:

```
ssh.connect('10.0.0.1', 'khangtt', str('12345')+str(otp), look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
```

Or

```
ssh.connect('10.0.0.1', 'khangtt', str('12345')+str(otp))
```

in case you don't need look for keys and allow agent.

Comment: Try setting the host key policy to: ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(
    paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

Comment: You can also find more documentations here: http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different